# Problema no retorno da função PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Boa tarde, pessoal estou iniciando no php e estou com um problema no meu código

```
  function buscarIdProduto($conn,$nome){
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM produto WHERE NOME_Produto = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $nome);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->get_result();
    return $resultado->fetch_assoc();
  }
```

nessa função eu pego o id do produto, o problema é que ela sempre retorna o id 1
ai quando vou inserir ele referencia ao produto com id 1.

```
if(inserirProduto($conn,$idCategoria,$nomeProduto,$descricao,$valor)){
      $produto = buscarIdProduto($conn,$nomeProduto);
}
inserirImagem($conn,$novoNome,$produto["id"],$upload,$tipo,$tamanho);
```

Comment: Fazer `bind_param("i", $nome)` indica que `$nome` será do tipo inteiro. Está certo isso? O nome não seria uma *string*?

Comment: É porque na verdade quero o id por isso passo no bind um inteiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt->bind_param("i", $nome);
```

Esta linha está incorreta. Você está passando `$nome` como um inteiro, mas como esta variável tem uma string alfanumérica nela, a sua função não consegue transformar letras em números.

O correto seria fazer `$stmt->bind_param("s", $nome);` ou `$stmt->bind_value("s", $nome);`.
A diferença entre os dois é que `bind_param` associa a variável à consulta, modificando a consulta quando o valor da variável é modificada e `bind_value` associa o valor da variável à consulta, mantendo a consulta do mesmo jeito mesmo que a variável seja modificada.

Comment: Isso, muito obrigado conseguir resolver meu problema ajudo muito.

Comment: Se você puder marcar a resposta como "aceita" eu agradeço